# How to find the relation between two models, and sort of inductive bias is that is implemented in those models

Tags: machine-learning, computation-models

I am pretty new with data science and Machine Learning. I am learning form one textbook and I found this task. I have no Idea from where to start and what relation could be. Any help would be great.

> Suppose we want to learn the Boolean functions in instance space
> $X=\{0,1\}^3$. We are given two models to examine: $H_1$ is the set of all
> logical functions in conjunctive normal form (CNF), $H_2$ is the set of
> logical functions which can be displayed in Horn form (disjunction
> of literals with at most one positive). I need to explain what is the
> relation between $H_1$ and $H_2$, and which sort of inductive bias is
> implemented in those models.

Comment: Please credit the original source of this task: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.

Comment: We're not looking for questions that are just the statement of an exercise-style task and a request for us to solve or an "I have no idea where to start".  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: A good starting point is to determine which functions belong to $H_1$ and which to $H_2$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I know the functions but do not know how to relate them to models beside for functions that p ∧ q ∧ ... ∧ t will be false for each